# Problems with inverse properties in owlready2

Tags: inverse

I encountered a difficulty:
I created an object property in owlready2 (for example: has_parent) and defined it as inverse of another one (for example: has_child). When I relate an individual (“John” for example) to the other (“Kevin” for example) by the first property to create “John has_parent Kevin” as a triple, it is expectable for the inverse triple “Kevin has_child John” to be created after the reasoning process. But it isn’t so. And when I Query “to which individual does relate Kevin by the has_child property” before the reasoning process, it answers: John!
But this is not the problem itself. The problem arises when I perform the reasoning process and then save both reasoning results and the main ontology itself: the triple “Kevin has_child John” doesn’t exist in the ontology, nor does in the reasoning results!

Another problem is that when I define a domain and a range for an object property in owlready2, and define another property to be the inverse of the first one, it is expectable for the domain and the range of the inverse property to be set as the range and the domain of the first one respectively after the reasoning. But it isn’t so. And no domain and range is set for the inverse property after reasoning.

I tried to define the inverse properties in another way but it wasn't successful.

heres the code:

```
from owlready2 import *
onto = get_ontology("http://test.org/Family#")
with onto:

    '''defining base classes'''
    class Human(Thing): pass
    class Man(Human): pass
    class Woman(Human): pass
    AllDisjoint([Man, Woman])

    '''defining properties'''
    class has_couple(Human>>Human): pass
    class has_wife(has_couple, Man>>Woman): pass
    class has_husbend(has_couple):
        inverse=has_wife
    class has_child (Human>>Human): pass
    class has_parent (ObjectProperty):
        inverse=has_child

    '''defining individuals'''
    John = Man("John")
    Kevin = Man("Kevin")

    '''defining relations between individuals'''
    John = Man("John", has_parent=[Kevin])

print(Kevin.has_child)

'''reasoning'''
with onto:
    sync_reasoner_pellet(infer_property_values=True, infer_data_property_values = True)

print(has_husbend.domain)

'''saving'''
onto.save("test.owl", format = "rdfxml")
```

Comment: Could you show the full code of how you create the ontology, how you check if triples exist, how you perform reasoning? That would help to find out 1) if there is a problem in your code, or 2) if you have a misunderstanding of what the inverse property does, or 3) if there is a bug in owlready2 itself.

Comment: I checked the existence of the triple in 2 ways: first by opening the saved ontology in protégé and second by searching the content of ontology itself in notepad
And here is the code I’ve written:

Comment: I added the code in the question above

Comment: another remarkable thing is that when I open the saved ontology again in another code,owlready2 recognizes the Kevin related to John by the property “has_child”. It means that owlready2 translate the triple “John has_parent Kevin” written in the ontology to the triple “Kevin has_child John“ which isn’t written in it without using any reasoner.
So until we use owlready2 as our owl api, there is no problem. The problem arises when we want to process the ontology in another owl api s

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only about the inverse property, not about the domain and range.

I could not verify it in the documentation but I assume it is a design decision of `owlready2` to implement the semantics of `owl:inverseOf`, and therefore return additional triples in a query, but to exclude these additional triples from the `save()` function.

The reason for this is the general principle that you should not add (redundant) triples to a knowledge base that were not present in the original ontology. Adding such triples automatically could cause a large and unwanted increase in file size and memory requirements, for example if there is a definition for an inverse property that applies to a property that each individual has.

Furthermore it is possible that the automatic application of the inverse semantics leads to incorrect facts for certain more complex relations, and you want a human-in-the-loop or some explainability algorithm to check if the results are correct. However, if you just enter the derived facts in the knowledge base then it is no longer possible to distinguish original facts from new facts, so in that case checking results (or even knowing that new facts have been added) is no longer possible.

In summary: this is expected behavior from `owlready2`. If you want to use the derived facts like *Kevin has_child John* then you should use `owlready2` itself or another engine that implements `owl:inverseOf`.

However, if you do want all triples in xml, then you can output them yourself using `rdflib` by looping over all instances, and for each instance looping over all properties.

Code:

```py
from owlready2 import *
from rdflib import Graph, URIRef, Namespace
from rdflib.namespace import RDF, RDFS, OWL

onto = get_ontology("http://test.org/Family#")

with onto:
    '''defining base classes'''
    class Human(Thing): pass
    
    class Man(Human): pass
    
    class Woman(Human): pass

    AllDisjoint([Man, Woman])

    '''defining properties'''
    class has_couple(Human>>Human): pass
    class has_wife(has_couple, Man>>Woman): pass
    class has_husband(has_couple):
        inverse=has_wife
    class has_child (Human>>Human): pass
    class has_parent (ObjectProperty):
        inverse=has_child

'''defining individuals'''
Kevin = Man("Kevin")

'''defining relations between individuals'''
John = Man("John", has_parent=[Kevin])
Mary = Woman("Mary", has_husband=[Kevin])

print("Kevin.has_child:", Kevin.has_child)
print("Kevin.has_wife:", Kevin.has_wife)

fam = Namespace("http://test.org/Family#")
graph = Graph(base="http://test.org/Family")
graph.bind('fam', fam)
A = RDF.type

for person in Human.instances():
    # add a node for this person
    graph.add((URIRef('#'+person.name), A, OWL.NamedIndividual))
    # add all rdf:type nodes (usually just 1)
    for entity_type in person.is_a:
        graph.add((URIRef('#'+person.name), A, URIRef('#'+entity_type.name)))
    # add all person-property-object triples
    for prop in person.get_properties():
        # a property can have multiple values
        for value in prop[person]:
            graph.add((URIRef('#'+person.name), fam.term(prop.name), URIRef('#'+value.name)))

# print xml, don't nest nodes (max_depth=1)
print(graph.serialize(format="pretty-xml", max_depth=1))
```

This prints the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://test.org/Family"
  xmlns:ns1="#"
  xmlns:fam="http://test.org/Family#"
  xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="#Mary">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Woman"/>
    <fam:has_husband rdf:resource="#Kevin"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="#Kevin">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Man"/>
    <fam:has_wife rdf:resource="#Mary"/>
    <fam:has_child rdf:resource="#John"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="#John">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Man"/>
    <fam:has_parent rdf:resource="#Kevin"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Some notes:

- I added an individual Mary with `has_husband=[Kevin]` to test the inverse has_husband/has_wife as well
- I corrected the spelling "husbend", correct is "husband"
- I tried to copy as much as possible the xml syntax used by `owlready2` itself. The only difference that I could not modify is that `owlready2` uses a plain relation `<has_child>` whereas `rdflib` with this code produces `<fam:has_child>` with the alias `fam:` for the namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.
I acknowledge what you said about putting not the inverse relations in the ontology itself because the reasoned results should be separated from asserted ontology. But it is expected that when we want to save the reasoning results, all of the reasoned results be saved including the inverse relations; the matter that does not occur in owlready2. So it is a deficiency as some parts of our knowledge are not represented in our xml or ttl or . . . file.

Comment: The solution you’ve mentioned can be easier done by one command of SPARQL as :
graph.update("""
               INSERT {?b ?d ?a.}
               WHERE {?a ?c ?b. ?c owl:inverseOf ?d.}""")

But my goal was to prove this deficiency of owlready2.
Anyway, I thank you for your valuable notes.

Comment: @ImanFarhadi it would indeed be desired if owlready2 would offer an optional export of all triples, including automatically derived triples. After all, if they are considered useful while running the code then these triples can also be useful in an exported ontology. You might try to get this functionality implemented by submitting a feature request at https://github.com/pwin/owlready2/issues.